# calculate the revenue contribution using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a table like this

```
item         mrp
-----       -----
burger       500
burger       500
burger       600
pizza        1000
pizza        1000 
pizza        1000
```

I need to calculate revenue contribution of burger and pizza. One way to do would be first getting sum of mrp of individual item and storing in a variable then getting sum of total mrp of all item, doing division.But this would require loop over individual item. I want to do it in a spark way using sql only. Is it possible or I have to choose the `looping` path

Answer (score 1):

You need to use groupby and agg.

First you sum up all the mrp:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val sumOfAll = df.agg(sum($"mrp")).collect()(0).getLong(0)
```

the agg functions allow you to aggregation. The sum function (from sql.functions) sums up all values in the mrp column. This results in a dataframe with one row and one column (just the sum). So we collect it to the driver, take the first element (there might in theory be multiple rows but we know only the first is relevant) which would result in a row and then we get the first column as a long.

```
val groupedDF = df.groupBy("item").agg(sum($("mrp") / lit(sumOfAll))
```

The groupBy tells us to do the agg calculation by item. We also divide the sum column by the sumOfAll from before (lit is literal, use the same value for all rows)

to see the results you can either use show (to view) or collect (to get and do something with it)

Comment: can you write it's java equivalent ?
currently I am using `  Dataset<Row> totalqty = spark.sql("select icode,bround(cast(sum(total_amount) as long)/(select cast(sum(total_amount) as long) from bigmart.o_sales)*100,2) as mrp from bigmart.o_sales group by icode");` 
this is helping me, but you code seems neat